# Computing Smith normal form in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in Python

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics, python

I am not sure if my question belongs here or more on stackoverflow as it concerns programming aspects of linear algebra. But I would like to compute the Smith normal form of a matrix $M$ with coefficient in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in Python.

I have come across the package Sympy that permit to do so via sympy.matrices.normalforms. This function allow specifying the domain of the matrix (see example here : https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/normalforms.html). Yet, as I am new to this package (and to formal calculus), I don't see how to specify that I am working in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ ?

If this is not possible, do you know any other package that would permit to do so ?

Comment: I've often just done this over the integers and then asked python to show it mod $p$ at the end. E.g. in this case working over the integers you compute matrix $D$ then type in $D\%2$.  If you understand how the ring homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb Z\longrightarrow \mathbb F_p$ works you'll see this gives the desired result [up to permutation similarity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FiniteField` to create finite fields. Then use the following code example:

```
from sympy import Matrix, FiniteField
from sympy.matrices.normalforms import smith_normal_form
    
m = Matrix([[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]])
F3 = FiniteField(3)
    
print(smith_normal_form(m, domain=F3))
```